# How to efficiently code for updating many variables in a script using Tkinter?

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I am designing a Tkinter interface to be compatible with my datalogging script. Both are still WIP, but close to getting merged. This script is used for a Raspberry Pi to periodically make measurements using different sensors. In this case, of plants.

I have various Entry widgets to access my variables (input channels, measure interval and measurements per average value ), so i can change them without reprogramming the script itself.

3 entry widgets are associated with the textvariables:
gpio_light1_entry, interval_light1_entry, amount_light1_entry

The actual variables used by the datalogging script are:
gpio_light1, interval_light1, amount_light1

I want to define a function (That i will bind to a button.). That retrieves the entry window value (gpio_light1_entry.get()) and that updates the script variable.

Now I could just use:

```
gpio_light1 = gpio_light1_entry.get()
```

However I have at least 12 variables per plant. So coding it like this for some 12 times seems very inefficient to me.

I was thinking of using a for loop and lists.

```
settings_gpio1 = [gpio_light1, gpio_temp1, etc]
settings_gpio1_entry = [gpio_light1_entry, gpio_temp1_entry, etc]
```

But this had some problems:
1- It seems that changing a value in a list, does not change the variable used to construct the list.
2- I do not know how to make a "double" for loop to use both the _entry and non entry lists.
3- The _entry list needs a .get() function to retrieve the values, this function does not work on lists directly, but can be solved with a for loop.

Does anyone know a more efficient or easier way to reach my goal?

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to create a class for each Gpio access:

The class it self should hold the values for accessing the hardware and displaying it.
If, for some reason, you already have the list of available gpios and entries, you can do some thing like this:

```
class Gpio:
    def __init__(self,setting, entry):
        self.setting = setting
        self.entry = entry
    def Get(self):
        #Do whatever you need with self.entry
        return 0
    def __str__(self):
        return self.setting
    @staticmethod
    def FromArray(names,settings, entries):
        assert(len(settings) == len(entries) == len(names))
        ret = {}
        for i in range(len(settings)):
            ret[names[i]] = Gpio(settings[i], entries[i])
        return ret
```

Here I put a random example, I don't know what values you are going to use:

```
gpio_light1 = 33
gpio_light_entry = "hardware_address"
gpio_temp_entry = "0x80001234"
names = ["gpio_light1", "gpio_temp1"]
settings_gpio = [gpio_light1, "gpio_temp1"] 
settings_gpio_entry = [gpio_light_entry, gpio_temp_entry]
access = Gpio.FromArray(names, settings_gpio, settings_gpio_entry)

print access["gpio_light1"].Get()
```